# Show last access time of the user

Tags: java, mysql

Could you please tell me how to get the last access time? So far, when I try to get it, it returns a `null` username.

Here is code in JSP:

```
<%   
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/lportal", "root", "root");
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

    String username = request.getParameter("username");  

    ResultSet resultset = 
        statement.executeQuery("select lastmodified from ams1 where username = '" + username + "'") ; 
    System.out.println(username);

%>

<% while(resultset.next()){ %>
    <p> last punchin: <%= resultset.getString(1) %> </p>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Can you give an example URI for this? Is `username` included as a parameter?

Comment: Oh boy, I hope your users' name is not <fakename>;DELETE <table> WHERE 1;. You shouldnt trust parameters sent from users. You could use PreparedStatment or some sanitization function to filter bad stuff

Comment: Improved readability, updated the title.